# Get time difference and show in proper format

Tags: php, mysql

I have two fields in database named start_time(12:30) and end_time(13:35). I want to show difference of them in "4hrs 30Mins" format. how can I get it done ?

Comment: @downvoters: Plz put comment if something wrong with my question. I might couldn't convince what exactly my requirement is ?

Comment: I did not downvote, but generally questions with some piece of broken code are more accepted around here... Better do a googling and look around and try something before asking.

Comment: @lhsan: thanks for your comment,But Im kind of stuck here, so any 1 having solutions plz let me know.

Comment: look John Conde's answer, full of hints....

Comment: I think you can remove the mysql tag for this question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some charity until this question gets deleted

```
$date1    = new DateTime($row['date1']);
$date2    = new DateTime($row['date2']);
$interval = $date2->diff($date1);
$period   = $interval->format('%y years, %m months, %d days, %h hours, %i minutes');
$period   = str_replace(array('0 years,', ' 0 months,', ' 0 days,', ' 0 hours,', ' 0 minutes,'), '', $period);
return str_replace(array('1 years, ', ' 1 months, ', ' 1 days, ', ' 1 hours, ', ' 1 minutes'), array('1 year, ', '1 month, ', ' 1 day, ', ' 1 hour, ', ' 1 minute'), $period);
```

**Reference**

- [DateTime Class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)
- [DatePeriod Class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php)
- [DateInterval Class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out myself, Thanks any way.

```
$from_time = strtotime($job->start_time);
$to_time = strtotime($job->end_time);
$mins=round(abs($to_time - $from_time) / 60,2);
$hrs=round($mins/60,2);
$arr=explode(".",$hrs);
echo $arr[0]." Hrs ".$arr[1]." Mins";
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick look at the PHP docs will point you in the right direction.

To compare the two dates, the [`diff` method of the DateTime object](http://au.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) may be of use.

Once you've done that, you could format it as you please with [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).